# A property of Kähler metric

Tags: differential-forms, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Given a Kähler manifold $(M,g)$ and the differential $\omega=\sqrt{-1} g_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}dz^{\alpha}\wedge dz^{\bar{\beta}}$, how to arrive the following results:

> $\omega$ is closed, i.e. $d\omega=0$ iff in terms of components of $g$, $$\frac{\partial g_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}}{\partial z^{\gamma}}=\frac{\partial g_{\gamma\bar{\beta}}}{\partial z^{\alpha}}.$$

I also wonder if the following property is true in complex manifold:
$dz^{i}\wedge dz^{j}=-dz^{j}\wedge dz^{i}$, $dz^{i}\wedge d\bar{z}^{j}=-d\bar{z}^{j}\wedge dz^{i}$ and $d\bar{z}^{i}\wedge d\bar{z}^{j}=-d\bar{z}^{j}\wedge d\bar{z}^{i}$.

The above questions seem to be easy but it take me a lot of time without correct derivations and answers. Could someone give detailed derivations and answer to the above problems?

Answer (score 1):

Write $\omega=\sqrt{-1} g_{j\bar k}dz^j\wedge d\overline{z}^k$. By definition
\begin{equation*}
d\omega=\sqrt{-1} \left(\frac{\partial g_{j\bar k}}{\partial z^l}dz^l\wedge dz^j\wedge d\overline{z}^k+ \frac{\partial g_{j\bar k}}{\partial\overline{z}^l}d\overline{z}^l\wedge dz^j\wedge d\overline{z}^k\right),
\end{equation*}
then $d\omega=0$ if and only if
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial g_{j\bar k}}{\partial z^l}=\frac{\partial g_{l\bar k}}{\partial z^j}.
\end{equation*}

---

Last equality follows by the definition of wedge product!

Comment: Thanks. However, one is $\frac{\partial}{\partial z^{l}}$ and the other one is $\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{z}^{l}}$. This two are not the same. How can I achieve the results? Could you explain a little bit more on using the definition of wedge product?

Comment: Let $\mathbb{V}$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$, of dimension $d\geq2$; for simplicity, $\bigwedge^2\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{V}\wedge\mathbb{V}=(\mathbb{V}\otimes\mathbb{V})/\langle a\otimes b+b\otimes a\mid a,b\in\mathbb{V}\rangle$, therefore $a\wedge b=[a\otimes b]_{\sim}=[-b\otimes a]_{\sim}=-b\wedge a$. I leave you the general case $\bigwedge^r\mathbb{V}$, with $r\in\{2,\dots,d\}$.

Comment: Thanks. So $d\bar{z}^{l}\wedge dz^{j}$ can be interchanged to $-dz^{j}\wedge d\bar{z}^{l}$. Changing the dummy variable, we still need to compute the following eaquality which I do not think is general true: $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} d\bar{z}=\frac{\partial}{\partial z} dz$

Comment: Because the matrix $(g_{jk})$ is Hermitian, one has the equivalence between $\displaystyle\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial z^l}=\frac{\partial g_{lk}}{\partial z^j}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial\overline{z}^l}=\frac{\partial g_{lk}}{\partial\overline{z}^j}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; but what you states should be the final results to be achieved.

Comment: $d\omega=0$ means $\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial z^{l}} dz^{l}\wedge dz^{j}\wedge d\bar{z}^{k}+\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial \bar{z}^{l}} d\bar{z}^{l}\wedge dz^{j}\wedge d\bar{z}^{k}=0$, which means that $\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial z^{l}} dz^{l}\wedge dz^{j}\wedge d\bar{z}^{k}-\frac{\partial g_{lk}}{\partial \bar{z}^{j}} dz^{l}\wedge d\bar{j}^{l}\wedge d\bar{z}^{k}=0$ (I apply the properties of wedge product and change the dummy variables).

Comment: Then I need to show that $\frac{\partial g_{lk}}{\partial \bar{z}^{j}} dz^{l}\wedge d\bar{z}^{j}\wedge d\bar{z}^{k}=\frac{\partial g_{lk}}{\partial {z}^{j}} dz^{l}\wedge d{z}^{j}\wedge d\bar{z}^{k}$. How to make use the Hermitian property? Would you mind pointing out which part should I use the property, or I cannot show in this way? If there is another direction, could you provide hits about it?

Comment: No, you need prove $\displaystyle\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial z^l}=\frac{\partial g_{lk}}{\partial z^j}\iff\frac{\partial g_{jk}}{\partial\overline{z}^l}=\frac{\partial g_{lk}}{\partial\overline{z}^j}$...

Comment: from my latest commnet, do you mean that I can change from $\bar{z}$ to $z$ using the hermit Ian property